# c# strings manipulation

Tags: c#, string

I have the following code where `frequencyOfReminders = "2 days"`

```
 dailyReminders = frequencyOfReminders.IndexOf("day", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

I want dailyReminders to be true should I use the below instead?

```
 dailyReminders = frequencyOfReminders.Contains("day", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

I should have been clearer. I have the string frequencyOfReminders= "2 days" for eg
and I want dailyreminders to return true if it finds the string "day" in frequencyOfReminders, other values where it would return true are : daily, 3 days, 1 day, ... etc

Comment: Can you please format the code parts as code?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: `daily` is not going to match `day`. Is that a typo?

Comment: sorry, i didnt mean to include daily....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The String.Contains method returns a boolean, so the >= 0 won't compile.

Should be like this:

```
dailyReminders = frequencyOfReminders.Contains("day", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

However, in this case I would lean towards Contains for readability.

**Edit:**

Oh, you're searching for multiple search terms.  In that case, one way to do it is with multiple Contains calls (straightforward):

```
dailyReminders = frequencyOfReminders.Contains("day", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                 || frequencyOfReminders.Contains("daily", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Another way is to get into regular expressions (fully explaining this approach will take some work), but here is a link that explains it:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

Regular expressions are incredibly powerful, but there is a learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

```
dailyReminders = frequencyOfReminders.Contains("day", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

does not requires >=0. In both  cases the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you should omit the '>=0' comparison when you use the .contains method. String.Contains(,) already returns a boolean:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The string function "Contains" does return a boolean, so something like

```
boolean dailyReminders = frequencyOfReminders.Contains("day");
```

would set dailyReminders to true.

Answer (score 0):

IndexOf returns -1 when the substring was not found so :

```
dailyReminders = frequencyOfReminders.IndexOf("day", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1
```